# Can't remove bluetooth mouse on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, mouse, bluetooth

I had issues with my bluetooth mouse today in that it lost connection. I switched bluetooth off and on again in settings and it still didn't work. So I removed the mouse from bluetooth by selecting Remove.

I tried to pair the mouse again, but windows can't find the mouse, with the mouse in pairing mode. I switched the mouse off, and then switched bluetooth off and on again in Windows.

The mouse reappeared in the bluetooth settings even though I had removed it. I tried to connect it to my PC again, but I think the pairing codes are now different so it doesn't connect. Even with the mouse switched off, if I switch bluetooth off and on again, the mouse reappears as paired like so:

[image]

I went to Device Manager and I Uninstall the bluetooth mouse from there and rebooted. When I go to bluetooth settings, the mouse reappears but I can't connect it.

It now seems that I can't remove it either.

Any ideas?

Comment: We may could try troubleshooting tool through control panel to check and repair bluetooth issue.

Answer (score 2):

An advice adapted from a
[Microsoft Technet article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/netro/2014/07/10/ghosted-or-not-removable-bluetooth-devices-on-surface-pro-2/) :

- Open Control Panel -> System
- Click the Advanced tab
- Click on the "Environment Variables" button
- Under "User variables for", click on "New"
- Add a variable named `devmgr_show_nonpresent_device` with the value if `1`
- Click OK
- Open Device Manager again
- Select menu *View > Show hidden devices*
- Right-click on the Bluetooth device and select *Uninstall*.

If this does not work, various other suggestions are to be found.
Here are a couple of useful posts:

- [Windows 10 failed to remove Bluetooth device](https://windowsreport.com/windows-10-remove-bluetooth-device/)
- [Unable to remove bluetooth device on windows 10](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking-winpc/unable-to-remove-bluetooth-device-on-windows-10/ea6da83d-583e-4b80-8714-367510879f07)

Comment: Unfortunately none of those suggestions worked. Whenever I switched bluetooth back on, the device popped back up again.

Comment: Is it related to some other application? Do you have other Bluetooth software that came with your network adapter? You might be looking in the wrong place.

Comment: No it's just a mouse, not a network adapter.

Comment: Meaning software that manages the network adapter you use to pair with Bluetooth devices.

Comment: What? I'm using Windows to pair Bluetooth devices. I installed the latest driver update for my bluetooth driver from Dell but it's still the same.

Comment: Windows is not supposed to remember uninstalled and non-existent devices. Problems like that are usually caused by third-party software.

Comment: I clean installed windows only two weeks ago.

Comment: The mouse will be re-discovered as long as it is turned on, but not paired.

Comment: My mistake was to try and re-pair it, now I'm stuck with a dead mouse.